# Multiple objects with one form and permitting parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

My rails app has a games model, and each game has multiple players. When a game is created, a set number of players are created with a default name like so:

```
def create
  @game = Game.new(game_params)
  @game.player_number.times do
    @game.players << Player.new(name: 'Santa')
  end
  if @game.save
    redirect_to action: "players", id: @game.id
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The redirect takes the user to a page that has a form with inputs for each player's name. The actions associated with this page are:

```
def players
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
end

def playersUpdate
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  puts player_params
  if @game.players.update(player_params)
    redirect_to @game
  else
    render 'players'
  end
end

private

def player_params
  params.require(players: [:name])
end
```

The editing page itself is:

```
<h2> Edit Players </h2>
<%= form_tag({:action => 'playersUpdate'},{:id => @game.id}) do %>
  <%= @game.players.count %>
  <% @game.players.each.with_index do |player,index| %>
    <%= fields_for "players[#{index}]", player do |pl| %>
      <div>
        <%= pl.label :name %><br>
        <%= pl.text_field :name %><br>
        <%= pl.hidden_field :id %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :games do
    collection do
      match "/:id/players" => "games#players", :via => :get
      match "/:id/players" => "games#playersUpdate", :via => :post
    end
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

I get an error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: {:players=>[:name]}
```

And I'm at a loss for what I could be missing. Any tips?

Here are the parameters being passed in, George is the name I'm trying to edit in, all others default to 'Santa':

```
Processing by GamesController#playersUpdate as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wNwt9v2ckO/Bl8YGr/a2CDCjSsRec30E51VjZ/Qv2i5BgEnzVbH5M9DsrVfCxdLusS4Ue6Mq+aPSFOiA4K5jJg==", "players"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"George", "id"=>"122"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Santa", "id"=>"123"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"Santa", "id"=>"124"}, "3"=>{"name"=>"Santa", "id"=>"125"}}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"22"}
```

Comment: You need to `require` or `permit` very specifically depending on what the incoming params look like. In your server logs, you should see a POST or PATCH request. Just below that you should see `Processing by YourController#playersUpdate as HTML`, and below that you should see the Parameters. Copy the Parameters and add them to your question.

Comment: Also, this is not the source of the problem, but your controller actions should be named using snake_case: `players_update` instead of `playersUpdate`. See the [style guide](https://github.com/github/rubocop-github/blob/master/STYLEGUIDE.md#naming) for more information.

Comment: I went ahead and added the Parameters you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You are not breaking any new ground here, and Rails has standard ways to do all of this. But it's easy to get "off the Rails" and make it harder than it needs to be.

Conceptually, stop thinking about updating a bunch of `Players`, and start thinking about updating a `Game` that happens to have some `Players`. The [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) are surprisingly helpful here.

Let's go first to your Game model. You'll need to tell it that it's OK to update nested attributes for players, like this:

```
# models/game.rb

model Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end
```

Your view is generating parameters that are not quite standard. Again, let Rails do the work for you. You don't need hidden fields or each_with_index. Since we're in Rails 5, let's use the new `form_with` helper, and we'll let `fields_for` do its job without our trying to tell it how to index:

```
# views/games/edit_players.html.erb

<h2> Edit Players </h2>
<%= form_with(model: game, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div>
    Game name: <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :players do |player_fields| %>
    <div>
      Player name: <%= player_fields.text_field :name %><br>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This will generate params that look something like this:

```
Parameters: {"game"=>
               {"name"=>"Risk", 
                "players_attributes"=>
                  {"0"=>{"name"=>"Abel", "id"=>"1"}, 
                   "1"=>{"name"=>"Baker", "id"=>"2"}, 
                   "2"=>{"name"=>"Charlie", "id"=>"3"}}}, 
                "commit"=>"Update Game", 
                "id"=>"1"}
```

Now you don't even need a custom update endpoint. Just use your standard `GamesController#update` action:

```
# controllers/games_controller.rb

class GamesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def edit_players
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])

    if @game.update(game_params)
      redirect_to @game
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name, players_attributes: [:id, :name])
  end
end
```

Finally, your routes file is confusing because you are using `collection` (which doesn't expect an :id) instead of `member`. The routes file should look something like this:

```
# routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :players
  resources :games do
    member { get :edit_players }
  end
end
```